# Getting a makefile to compile different programs depending on a commandline input

Tags: c, linux, unix, makefile

I'm pretty new to makefiles so please forgive me if this is a bit of a dumb question. I'm trying to get my makefile to compile a program with slightly different files, depending on if an input is specified, when "make" is used. Using linux.

basically when the user inputs "make STRCHECKER" I want it to compile a different program to when the user inputs "make INDEX"

This is what i have currently(but it keeps saying its overwritten itself):

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic - ansi -Werror

STRCHECKER:                      //to compile stringchecker

stringchecker : main.o stringchecker.o
    gcc main.o stringchecker.o -o stringchecker.exe

main.o : main.c stringchecker.h
gcc -c main.c $(CFLAGS)

stringchecker.o : stringchecker.c stringchecker.h
gcc -c stringchecker.c $(CFLAGS)

INDEX:                         //to compile index

stringcheckerINDEX : main.o stringcheckerINDEX.o
    gcc main.o stringcheckerINDEX.o -o stringcheckerINDEX.exe

main.o : main.c stringcheckerINDEX.h
gcc -c main.c $(CFLAGS)

stringcheckerINDEX.o : stringcheckerINDEX.c stringcheckerINDEX.h
gcc -c stringcheckerINDEX.c $(CFLAGS)
```

I was just wondering what the correct way to do this is

Comment: Have you considered using different names for the executables produced from different sources?  Or at least putting them in different directories? As it is, The difficulty you are having with `make` is a foreshadowing of the confusion that is likely to arise from trying to use the program(s).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks john I changed it so that the executable has a different name i just want to know, when you run the make command how to get it to make one or the other because at the moment my makefile just tries to make both

Comment: If indeed `make` was building the executable twice, according to the two different rules for the same target name, then it was very likely because you had two different rules, with recipes, for the same target name (`stringchecker.exe`).  That is not allowed, and I expect that fixing it resolved any multi-building that was happening.

Comment: but when I run "make INDEX" shouldnt it just compile everything under index and not for strchecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the name of any target in your makefile and make will attempt to build it.  If you don't give any target name, make will attempt to build the *first* target in your makefile (and any of its prerequisites of course) then stop.

Also remember that, like all right-thinking software :), make is case-sensitive so `STRCHECKER` and `strchecker` are different targets.

So with your makefile you can run `make strchecker.exe` and it will build the target `strchecker.exe`.

Also you don't say what platform you're building for but note that for POSIX-style platforms like GNU/Linux or MacOS, it is not common to add a suffix like `.exe` to executables.  So if you're on a platform like that you could just make the target `strchecker` instead of `strchecker.exe`.

If you want to continue to use `strchecker.exe` and still be able to run just `make strchecker` without the `.exe` suffix you can add this to your makefile:

```
strchecker: strchecker.exe
```

so that when you build the `strchecker` target it will build all of its prerequisites (i.e., `strchecker.exe`).

Comment: Thank you for helping. I edited my file so that there's no .exe but when I run it it still says "makefile warning: overriding recipie for target 'main.o'" "warning ignoring old recipe for target main.o" and then it says "make: nothing to be done for INDEX

Comment: Well, you have a target `INDEX:` which has no dependencies and no rule for how to build it.  So, when you ask to build it make has nothing to do.  You seem to be thinking that by putting `INDEX:` there you're creating some kind of subsection of a makefile so that all rules after that are part of that subsection, then you can define the same target in each subsection and use `make INDEX` to choose that subsection.  That's not how make works.  All targets defined in the makefile are added to a single directed graph (which may have many roots).

Comment: You have defined two different recipes for building `main.o`.  You can only have one recipe to build a given target, so make replaces the first with the second and prints a warning about it.  If you need to compile `main.c` two different ways (which you don't seem to do actually) then you need to create two different output files with different names.  If you don't need to compile `main.c` different ways, then you only need one rule, not two.